# Convert Decision Tree classifier to MLmodel

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, coreml, mlmodel

I have trained DecisionTree classifier which contains 3 .pkl file (`decision_tree_classifier.pkl`, `count_vectorizer.pkl`, `label_encoder.pkl`). Now i want to convert it into .mlmodel for IOS.

I am using below code to convert model to .mlmodel but it does not include `label_encoder` and `count_vectorizer`. How can I do this?

```
import coremltools
# Convert the decision tree model to Core ML
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.sklearn.convert(clf)

# Save the Core ML model to a file
coreml_model.save('core_mlmodel.mlmodel')
```